# Child theme won't override default files

Tags: theme, magento2.2

I'm developing with Magento 2.2.2 and I'm trying to create my own child-theme that inherits from the default blank theme.
I tried to override the `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` file with my own theme but it still grabs list.phtml when using my new theme.
I copied list.phtml from the vendor and pasted it to `MyVendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/templates/product` but I can't get it to work.

I tried cleaning the cache, deploying static files, deleting `var/cache`, `pub/static`, `var/view_preprocessed`, `var/page_cache` but nothing seems to work.

It seems like an easy thing to do but I can't find what is wrong with my theme because it still uses the default file. I know this because I am using hints on the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change this:

`MyVendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/templates/product`

with this:

`MyVendor/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check below correct path

```
MyVendor/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```